# How to read from a file the '\n' character

Tags: c++

The problem with my code is that it never gets into the if.
In other words it never reads the '\n' character.
The '\n' exists in the file I want to read and it is important
to read it in order to save the matrix the right way.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char **argv){

  int N, M;
  int n, m;
  int i, j;
  char a;
  ifstream myfile;
  string txt;
  char mat[1000][1000];

  txt = argv[1];
  myfile.open(txt);

  n = 0;
  m = 0;
  while(myfile >> a){
    if(a == '\n'){
      n++;
      m = 0;
      continue;
    }

      mat[n][m] = a;
      m++;
  }

  myfile.close();
  cout << n << " " << m;
  for(i=0; i<=n; i++){
    cout << endl;
    for(j=0; j<m; j++){
      cout << mat[i][j] << " ";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your file does not contain any newlines? We can't really help without a [mcve] + some example input data.

Comment: What is the type of `a`? Please post some compilable code.

Comment: edited guys
I'm sorry new here

Comment: Rather than post everything, post a complete program that does only the minimum required to demonstrate the problem. A simple solution to your problem is outlined in Option 2 in [this linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/4581301).

Comment: `myfile >> a` skips whitespace.  It appears you want to get a character at a time, and not skip whitespace.  The operator `>>` streaming is the wrong thing to use for this situation.  Use this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/

Answer (score -1):

There are two equivalent functions for entering a character — `getc ()` and `fgetc ()`. Support two identical functions

The `getc()` function is used to read characters from a stream opened for reading with `fopen()`. The `getc()` prototype is as follows:

```
int getc(FILE * fp);
```

where fp is a pointer to a file type FILE * returned by `fopen()`. Traditionally, `getc()` returns an integer, but the high byte is set to 0.

The `getc()` function returns EOF when the end of the file is reached. To read the text file to the end, use the following code:

```
ch = getc(fp);
while (ch! = EOF) 
{
  enter code here`ch = getc (fp);
}
```

Or you can try

```
if(a == '\')
```